# How are unseeded players, players with PR, qualifiers and wildcard positions determined in a Grand Slam singles main draw?

Tags: tennis, grand-slam

How are unseeded players, players with protected ranking, qualifiers and wildcards positioned in a Grand Slam singles main draw? Is it a generic random allocation or is it based on a formula/method specific to each Grand Slam?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, random allocation.

See the following section in the official [ITF Grand Slam rulebook](https://www.itftennis.com/officiating/rulebooks/grand-slams.aspx) (note that Wild Cards may be seeded):

> Z. ENTRY PROCEDURES / 2. Singles Main Draw / g. Method of Draw

Text excerpt:

> **g. Method of Draw** 
>   A draw sheet for 128 places will be used. The placement
>   of seeds as heretofore provided. The remaining players, including the
>   Qualifiers, will be drawn and placed into the vacant spaces in the
>   draw, beginning at the top of the draw.